# How to show the "add to home screen" popup window and notifications like the buildin home app?

Tags: android

The Home sample in the android sdk doesn't implement the Add item, which bring up the "Add to home screen" popup window, and Notifications item in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`.

How to do that like the default home app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I find myself asking "how do they do that?" then I go over to https://android.googlesource.com and look and see.  Or (more frequently) I google search my question with `site:https://android.googlesource.com` appended to the query.

Anyway, [here is how the android launcher does it](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java#1042), or close enough for you to trace to the implementation you're looking for (I didn't catch exactly what you're trying to do).

Comment: Can u please tell me how to use this google git. i cant understand how to use?